# problem when installing vanilla texlive on debian

Tags: installing

I am following [this installation of TexLive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) on Debian, but when typing `equivs-build texlive-local` terminal returns:

```
user@huayra:/tmp/tl-equivs$ equivs-build texlive-local
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_install
dh_installdocs
dh_installchangelogs
dh_compress
dh_fixperms
dh_installdeb
dh_gencontrol
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: file FcntlLock not available, flock will be user but it is unsafe on NFS environment.
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package `texlive-local' en `../texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb'.

The package has been created.
Attention, the package has been created in the current directory,
not in ".." as indicated by the message above!
user@huayra:/tmp/tl-equivs$
```

Then, when i type:

```
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb 
dpkg: texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb contains texlive-local:
 texlive-base conflict with texlive-common
  texlive-local gives texlive-common and is going to be installed.

dpkg: error processing file texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb (--install):
 packages in conflict - it won't be installed in texlive-local_2017
Errors were found when processing:
 texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb
```

I have translated the words because it is in Spanish.
Any idea what is going bad?

ps: I posted here because there is a tag about ´installation´ of Latex.

Comment: Do you already have any of the debian/Ubuntu texlive packages installed? You should not when installing the equivs package. Have you tried `dpkg --get-selections | grep texlive`

Comment: @daleif the command returns: `texlive-base install texlive-binaries install`

Comment: Then you already have some LaTeX stuff installed which conflicts with the stuff in the equivs package. You probably need to remove `texlive-base`  and `texlive-binaries`

Comment: @daleif any way to know it was correctly installed?

Comment: It will not complain. Basically the equivs package tells the system that equivalents to several packages have already been installed through other means. This of course gives problems if some of the stuff on the equivs list is already installed (as you experienced). It is most likely that you installed those `texlive- ` packages as part of recommends to some editor or similar.

Comment: @daleif right, I understand. Thanks. What you thought worked, and I have previously installed Texmaker, that could be the source of trouble isn't it? Then I modified the path to latex and pdflatex in texmaker (I suppose it is good cause it is compiling).

Comment: @daleif would you post your comments as an answer? I think it could be useful (at least to myself in other installation haha). Just with the first comment and your solution will work. Also I have installed Fcntlock (look at the post, it wasn't installed)

Comment: @daleif Fcntlock install was done with `sudo apt-get install libfile-fcntllock-perl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using/building the equivs package to tell a Debian based system that you have installed something similar to the Debian `texlive-` packages, most often because you have installed upstream TeX Live (from TUG) it is importan that you do not have any of the packages listed in the equivs package list installed already.

It is kind of hard trying to convince the package manager that you have installed something equivalent to, say, `texlive-base` when `texlive-base` is already installed on your system.

`texlive-base` and others can easily "sneak" it self onto your system as part of recommended packages for other programmes you have installed (like LaTeX editors).

To check if you have any of the Debian TeX live packages installed try

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep texlive
```

it should not give any answers like `texlive-base` etc.

Once you have successfully installed the equivs build package, the only thing on on that list should be `texlive-local`

Once you install the equivs build `texlive-local` package, the package manager may report that some dependencies from the `texlive-local` package is missing on your system. This can often be fixed using

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then it fixes itself and installs the extra dependencies needed.